# Find and store DB relationships in MySQL / PHP

Tags: php, mysql

Scenario: many to many relationships.

table has 2 columns: UserID and UserChoiche

I am storing the user preferences one by one in each row.
(Is this the most efficient way?)

Example:

```
UserID         UserChoiche
```

`mark`                                                     `anna`
`mark`                                                       `paul`
`mark`                                                       `john`
`john`                                                       `mark`

In this example mark chose 3 users, and john chose 1 user.

John and Mark have chosen each other and I need php to find this db relationship.

//php mysql query that selects all the choiches of a specified user (in this case mark)
`SELECT UserChoiche from exampletable WHERE UserID mark`

//find the matches 
?? 
here is my problem: I am looking for the easiest and most efficent way to handle this!

Maybe like this? (It could work but I cannot write a mysql statement, is too complicated for me!) 
`If Userchoice of previous query (in this case it would return anna paul and john) EQUALS any Userid in the table (in this case john) AND that Userid has a Userchoiche with the value of the UserID from the previous query (in this example 4th row)` 
then we have a match

//if matches found, then take the UserID and UserChoiche and store them into variables which I will use to make some notifications (there can be many matches, so maybe use an array?)

Comment: It sounds like you're looking for a self join.  Take a look at this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1284441/how-does-a-mysql-self-join-work

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
SELECT t1.UserID, t2.UserID
FROM table t1, table t2
WHERE t1.UserID = t2.UserChoiche
   AND t2.UserID = t1.UserChoiche
```

That should spit out the two that chose each other. We are basically joining the table to itself to find the mutual relationship

Answer (score 2):

Here's the query to return users that match `mark`. Given the above data, it would return `john`:

```
SELECT p2.UserID
FROM preferences p1
JOIN preferences p2
ON p2.UserID = p1.UserChoice
AND p1.UserChoice = p2.UserID
WHERE p1.UserID = 'mark'
```

Comment: I like it and it seems to work (testing still in progress), but could you please clarify what p1 and p2 are?

Comment: ok now I figured out everything and it works perfectly! thanks!

Comment: `p1` and `p2` are [table aliases](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/select.html). Another way to write the query is `FROM preferences AS p1`, which makes it more obvious that it's an alias. Aliases allowed me to reference the same table by two different, abbreviated, names.

Comment: WARNING: I changed my answer to mattedgod. Your answer seemed to work, but when I tested on a more complicated environment --> IT GAVE ME FALSE RESULTS. Maybe if you look at mattedgod's answer you can understand why yours is not completely working, honestly I have no clue why! Thanks anyway..

Comment: @MarkBelli, you're right. There was an error in my query. There was a missing criteria, which I added (see the AND part). This is basically now nearly identical to mattedgod's answer except I am using ANSI standard joins.