# SQL Query for "almost" duplicate entries (same values for last 3 columns)

Tags: mysql, sql

I need help with an SQL-Query. I have one table with many entries and I want to query all the entries which have the same values for the last 3 columns.

My table looks as follows:

```
|Refrigator|98C08A|2011-08-06 00:00:30|126|126
|Refrigator|B7BE29|2011-08-06 00:00:30|73|70
|Refrigator|599393|2011-08-06 00:00:30|126|126
|Refrigator|B7BE29|2011-08-06 00:00:29|73|70
|Refrigator|599393|2011-08-06 00:00:29|126|126
|Refrigator|599393|2011-08-06 00:00:29|126|126
|Refrigator|98C08A|2011-08-06 00:00:29|126|126
|Refrigator|98C08A|2011-08-06 00:00:29|126|126
|Refrigator|599393|2011-08-06 00:00:28|126|126
```

So I want to get all rows, which have the exact same values for the last 3 columns, so the result should look like:

```
|Refrigator|98C08A|2011-08-06 00:00:30|126|126
|Refrigator|599393|2011-08-06 00:00:30|126|126
|Refrigator|599393|2011-08-06 00:00:29|126|126
|Refrigator|599393|2011-08-06 00:00:29|126|126 (if possible without this duplicate)
|Refrigator|98C08A|2011-08-06 00:00:29|126|126
|Refrigator|98C08A|2011-08-06 00:00:29|126|126 (if possible without this duplicate)
```

Does anyone have an idea how to manage this?
What I tried so far was:

```
SELECT * 
FROM smtab 
WHERE Datetime IN (
      SELECT Datetime 
      FROM smtab 
      GROUP BY Datetime 
      HAVING count(Datetime) >1) 
AND Power1 IN (
      SELECT Power1 
      FROM smtab 
      GROUP BY Power1 
      HAVING count(Power1) >1) 
AND Power8 IN (
      SELECT Power8 
      FROM smtab 
      GROUP BY Power8 
      HAVING count(Power8) >1) 
ORDER BY Datetime DESC;
```

but I didn't work!!!

Hope someone can help me! thx in advance...

Comment: The rows you give in your example result do not have identical values for the last 3 columns.

Comment: This related article might be of interest http://beemerguy.net/blog/post/How-to-remove-duplicate-SQL-table-entries-(by-example).aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT DISTINCT *
FROM   smtab NATURAL JOIN (
  SELECT   Datetime, Power1, Power8
  FROM     smtab
  GROUP BY Datetime, Power1, Power8
  HAVING   COUNT(*) > 1
) AS t
```

Comment: Wow, thx a lot! This is a very elegant solution and works like a charm!

Comment: This worked perfect for my above mentioned scenario!
Now I have another constraint which restricts the number of duplicates which should be replied even further (to a certain limited timespan).

So I need all duplicates where for example:
Where Datetime > '2011-08-06 00:00:00'' AND Datetime < '2011-08-07 00:00:50'
I tried several modifications with your solution, but I couldn't get it to work as expected. :( Any idea how I can manage that?

Comment: @funkypopcorn: Add a `WHERE` clause to the subquery-e.g. `... FROM smtab WHERE Datetime BETWEEN '2011-08-06 00:00:00' AND '2011-08-07 00:00:50' GROUP BY ...`?

Comment: ahhhh thx a lot, I always put the Where-clause at the wrong position! :)

Comment: sry for asking again but I'm really lacking db-knowledge or sql-knowledge and things get more and more complicated.
-> Maybe you can also help me with the following follow-up question:
http://stackoverflow.com/q/11072721/1424439

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are looking for a **self-join**.  Take a look at [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1284441/how-does-a-mysql-self-join-work) to get started.  You don't mention which columns you wish to exclude so I can't really provide any code.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that you need to identify the duplicates, the inner join, then find everything that matches.

The `distinct` enables only one of each duplicate to be returned.

```
-- only select one of each duplicate.
select distinct *
  from smtab as a
        -- Find the duplicates
  join ( select datetime, power1, power8
           from smtab
          group by datetime, power1, power8
         having count(*) > 1) as b
      -- join back on to the main table
    on a.datetime = b.datetime
   and a.power1 = b.power1
   and a.power8 = b.power8
```

You're looking for a duplicate across all 3 columns, rather than each individually. Hence you have to group by all 3 simultaneously to find your duplicates.

Answer (score 0):

This approach works in my data model, with SQL Server. Not sure if it works with MySQL. I'm joining a table to a derived query. The derived query finds all records that have > 1 record.

```
select * from Employees as e
 inner join
(
select LastName, firstname from Employees 
 group by LastName, FirstName having COUNT(1) > 1
) as derived
on e.LastName = derived.lastname and e.FirstName = derived.firstname
order by e.LastName
```

EDIT:
To make it more related to your data model, try something like this:

```
SELECT * FROM smtab as s
  inner join 
(
  select datetime, power1, power8 
    from smtab as s2
   group by s2.datetime, power1, POWER8 having COUNT(1) > 1
) as derived
on s.datetime = derived.datetime and s.power1 = derived.power1 
and s.power8 = derived.power8
ORDER BY Datetime DESC;
```