# SQL: merge data from multiple rows

Tags: mysql, sql, itunes, spotify

I currently have this sql data:

```
id  track_name  artist_name media   source  is_correct  is_found

    9   track1          1           *****   spotify false           true
    10  track2          2           *****   itunes  false           true
    11  track3          3           *****   spotify false           true
    12  track4          4               *****   itunes  false           true
```

I need a sql query which results every song witch both (itunes & spotify) media.
Is thre any way i can do this?

Comment: how many source do you have?

Comment: two, but i would really like to make it dynamic, so unlimited

Comment: select * from table_name where source IN ("spotify", "itunes") is my first guess from what you are asking, however the question is a little vague. What are you trying to accomplish? This may help us help you.

Comment: I thought about grouping the data, and use the having clause like group by source having count(*) = 2

Comment: I wish to compare the cover art, so I want to place both cover arts next to eachother so I can tell wich is the correct album art for my application

Comment: With SELECT * FROM songs WHERE source IN ('itunes','spotify'); I still get seperate rows. I would like to get both media in ONE row

Comment: check out this post, you are looking for a pivot table http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12598120/mysql-pivot-table-query-with-dynamic-columns

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
select * from tablename where  media IN ('itunes','spotify')
```

Answer (score 0):

I have my doubts that the cover art images will be identical, but barring that you need to join to your own table.

[How does a MYSQL Self-Join Work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1284441/how-does-a-mysql-self-join-work)

```
select track1.id, track2.id 
from tablename track1
join tablename track2
where track1.media = track2.media and track1.source <> track2.source;
```