# Select all related values in a many-to-many relationship

Tags: mysql, sql, many-to-many

In a many-to-many relationship MySql DB, I need to select all resources (documents with titles) that belong to the categories in a list (categories with the id 9,10 in the example below).

Here is the model:

[image]

*However, and this is the important thing*: for each resource I want to also get ALL the categories that resource has associated with it - not just the ones queried for...
So if the resource with title: title_1 matches categories with id 9 and 10 for instance, but if that resource in fact also has category 11 and 12, I would want to get that information.

So for a query asking for the resource where category matches either 9 or 10, I would want that resource, and all of its associated categories. I.e the information I need for such a resource is:

resource title: title_1
categories: 9,10,11,12

Even though I only specified that it needed to match 9 and 10 in the query…

The reason for this is that if a user searches based on a couple of categories, the results should still give all the information about that object regarding all the categories set on it.

What I have so far is this:

```
SELECT
     r.title,
      cr.category_id
FROM
     category_resource cr
          INNER JOIN resource r
          ON cr.resource_id = r.id
WHERE cr.category_id IN (9,10)
```

This gives me rows with resources tagged with either of these, very fast (about 10 ms) from a DB of 5000 rows. The result is 3 titles:

title_1, category: 9
title_1, category 10
title_2, category: 10

I.e, I’m getting two results for title_1, because it has both category 9 and 10. But I only get these two categories because they were in the query. But this does not give me the other categories associated with the resource title_1.

Note that I have asked a similar question before, but not quite. I got an answer to that one that sort of resolved it. But it got too complex and I needed to rephrase it and also give it a different focus. The point is here: I need to get this info, but it also must be almost as fast as the current simpler query I have, i.e around 10 ms. That may be asking a lot, but at the same time the requirement doesn’t seem too far-fetched to me for a database? I.e get an item matching a criterion, and get all the values associated with in from a many-to-many relationship table…

Being far from an expert in this area, still this seems to me what relational databases should be made for,  handling queries on relationships…so I feel like there must be a simple and efficient solution to this problem, and I just hope I am able to explain it clearly enough…

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can accomplish this with a [Self-Join](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1284441/how-does-a-mysql-self-join-work):

Here is a working sqlfiddle:  http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/1826f/6

You already joined on category_resource to limit to (9,10), so we join on a copy of it and get all the results that match:

```
SELECT
     r.title,
      cr2.category_id
FROM
     category_resource cr
INNER JOIN resource r
ON cr.resource_id = r.id
INNER JOIN category_resource cr2 on cr2.resource_id = r.id
WHERE cr.category_id IN (9,10)
GROUP BY cr2.category_id,r.title
ORDER BY r.title
```

Edit based on comment:
If you are requiring ALL categories (9,10) you could change it to self-join AGAIN as cr3:

```
SELECT
 r.title,
 cr2.category_id
FROM
 category_resource cr
INNER JOIN resource r
ON cr.resource_id = r.id
INNER JOIN category_resource cr2 on cr2.resource_id = r.id
INNER JOIN category_resource cr3 on cr3.resource_id = r.id
WHERE cr.category_id = 9
and cr3.category_id = 10
GROUP BY cr2.category_id,r.title
ORDER BY r.title
```

sqlfiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/1826f/11

OR here is the version using HAVING: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/1826f/12

```
SELECT
 r.title,
 cr2.category_id
FROM
 category_resource cr
INNER JOIN resource r
ON cr.resource_id = r.id
INNER JOIN category_resource cr2 on cr2.resource_id = r.id
WHERE cr.category_id IN (9,10)
GROUP BY cr2.category_id,r.title
HAVING count(cr.category_id)=2
ORDER BY r.title
```

Comment: Thanks, need to test it a bit, but it seems to be working very well! Could you please add how to modify this to require that cr. category_id must match ALL in the list (9,10) also? This is another option I need... I know this is usually done by adding something like HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT cr.category_id) = 2 (for a list of two values that is), but I tried and I cannot put this together with that to get a valid statement...

Answer (score 0):

Try using a left join instead of the inner join.  I think that might be what you are looking for, but I am not certain that I have followed your description properly.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so

```
SELECT
      r.title,
      cr.category_id
FROM
     category_resource cr
          INNER JOIN resource r
          ON cr.resource_id = r.id
WHERE cr.category_id IN (9,10)
```

Gives you all the resources that have category id of 9 or 10.

If you modify this a bit

```
   SELECT DISTINCT
          r.title,
          cr2.category_id
    FROM
         category_resource cr
    INNER JOIN resource r
              ON cr.resource_id = r.id
     INNER JOIN category_resource  cr2
              ON cr.resource_id = cr2.resource_id
    WHERE cr.category_id IN (9,10)
```

You should be able to grab the other resource categories besides 9 and 10.

That being said, I don't know that I entirely follow your schema. So let me explain in plain English.

Modify the query that shows all resources with categories 9 or 10.
Add another inner join to the table that contains every title/category pair (this is where I'm not sure I follow your schema). Join on the title. Get the additional categories from the table that contains the title/category pair.

You can optimize this by deduping the resource titles you'll use to join to the resource table the second time you use it. But hopefully this will get you started :-)