# Select Transitive Relation on One Table

Tags: mysql, sql

I have one table (in MySQL) like this:

```
subject | predicate | object
A       | P1        | X
X       | P2        | B
```

I want to know transitive relation by using this table, so the result should like this:

```
element1 | predicate1 | pivot | predicate2 | element2
A        | P1         | X     | P2         | B
```

I have been tried to construct the query by using nested query, but in the end i have syntax error (I think `p2` (in nested query) cannot be determined in main query)

```
select p1.subject, p1.predicate, p1.object, p2.predicate, p2.object 
from some_relation p1 
where p1.subject = 'A' 
and p1.object = (select p2.subject from some_relation p2 where p2.object = 'B');
```

Anyone know how to do this kind of query? Is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a [self join](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1284441/how-does-a-mysql-self-join-work):

```
SELECT 
a.subject as element1, 
a.predicate as predicate2, 
a.object as pivot, 
b.predicate as predicate2, 
b.subject as element2 FROM
table a JOIN
table b ON a.object = b.subject;
```

Comment: I choose your answer as accepted answer because of the reference link! Thank u for all the answer.

Answer (score 1):

I would write a simple `JOIN`:

```
select p1.subject, p1.predicate, p1.object, p2.predicate, p2.object 
from some_relation p1 
inner join some_relation p2 on p1.object = p2.subject and p2.object = 'B'
where p1.subject = 'A'
```

Or do you mean something different?

Answer (score 1):

You'd have to join the table with itself:

```
select p1.subject, p1.predicate, p1.object, p2.predicate, p2.object 
from some_relation p1 inner join some_relation p1  
  on p1.object = p2.subject
where p1.subject = 'A';
```

Please note that you cannot do this indefinitely. E.g., the above query only can return one "hop". If you have a transitive chain, that's hard to impossible to do in plain SQL.