# MySQL - Finding mismatches between sets of "batched" data

Tags: mysql, sql, select, join

I have a table of customer order data that looks like this:

[image]

As you can see, there's a row for billing and a row for shipping for EACH order. `parent_id` is what tethers these rows together in to one order. What I need to do is write a query that finds all cases where there's a `last_name` OR `zip_code` mismatch between two rows with the same `parent_id` (i.e. the billing and shipping info is different). I'm at something of a loss for how to construct this query because this doesn't work for pretty obvious reasons:

```
SELECT * 
FROM order_addresses 
WHERE parent_id = parent_id
AND last_name <> last_name
```

What I think I need to really do is find all cases where `parent_id` matches FIRST and then step down and see whether `zip_code` and `last_name` also match and display all results where they do not. I don't know how to do that. Any pointers would be great, thank you!

Comment: I don't like the way that table is designed. Ideally you would have columns each for shipping and billing information rather than a column that tells you which it is.

Comment: I agree, but I didn't design the table. This table exists (along with many tables like it) thanks to Magento, and I simply have to live with it. :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about the following:

```
SELECT * 
FROM order_addresses o1
  INNER JOIN order_addresses o2 
  ON o1.parent_id = o2.parent_id 
  AND o1.entity_id <> o2.entity_id
WHERE o1.last_name <> o2.last_name
  OR o1.zip_code <> o2.zip_code
```

Comment: You should add the zip code logic to fully answer the question.

Comment: and 
1. correct the typo in "parrent_id" 
2. select fields from either o1 or o2, i.e. SELECT o1.* instead of SELECT * to avoid duplicate records

Comment: **@Gordon** and **Haleemur Ali**, thanks for the observations.  I missed the zip code requirement.  I also fixed the `parent_id` spelling.

Comment: Brilliant! Thank you. I didn't realize you were able to specify table "instances"...

Comment: It's called a self-join - More info here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1284441/how-does-a-mysql-self-join-work

Comment: Thanks for the info Phrancis - can you join other external tables in to the query if you're using self-joins? That's the next step...

Comment: yes you can join as many tables as you want and the same table several times.

Answer (score 0):

This is my take on this. Not 100% certain it will work. [You might be able to pivot it too if you want to look into that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7674786/mysql-pivot-table). This is really not good table design.

```
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS sp_BillShipCompare;
CREATE PROCEDURE sp_BillShipCompare();

DELIMITER //

SET @start = (SELECT MIN(parent_id FROM order_addresses);
SET @stop = (SELECT MAX(parent_id FROM order_addresses);

WHILE @start <= @stop DO
BEGIN

SELECT 
    oab.zip_code AS 'billing_zip',
    oas.zip_code AS 'shipping_zip',
    oab.name AS 'billing_name',
    oas.name AS 'shipping_name'
FROM order_addresses AS oab
INNER JOIN order_addresses AS oas
ON oab.parent_id = oas.parent_id
WHERE oab.parent_id = @start
OR oas.parent_id = @start
AND oab.address_type = 'billing'
AND oas.address_type = 'shipping'
AND oab.zip_code <> oas.zip_code
OR oab.name <> oas.name;
SET @start = @start+1;
END;
END WHILE//

DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: Linger's way is better.

Comment: Yeah, the table design sucks. Thanks Magento. ;)