# SQL where exists while preserving values between them

Tags: mysql, sql

Well, I have 2 tables like this: 
    Table1

```
ID | USER_ID  
1    0      
2    2       
3    15      
4    16
```

Table2

```
ID | FROM | TO 
9    0      2 
9    2      16 
9    16     15 
9    15     0 
10   15     2
```

What I want is really simple but driving me crazy, considering that `ID` , `FROM` and `TO` represents users in table 2. I want to get someone in `FROM` (which is Table1.user_id) with an `ID` in table2 such as it also `exists` in `TO` (which is the same Table1.user_id) with the same `ID` of table2

For example, record 16 is eligible. Because it appears in From with `ID` of 9 and as `TO` with the same `ID` of 9 in table 2 (both TO and FROM correspond to a user_id of 15 in table1)

What I have done was:

```
select * 
from `Table1` 
where exists (select ID from `Table2` as p1 where FROM = 16) 
      and exists (select ID from `Table2` as p2 where ID = 16) 
      and p1.ID = p2.ID
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This may work;

```
select * from table1 a where a.USER_ID in 
(select b.FROM from table2 b
where exists (select c.id from table2 c
where b.id = c.id and b.FROM = c.TO) )
```

Comment: I've updated the question with more details .. please check it

Answer (score 1):

You could try using a [self join](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1284441/how-does-a-mysql-self-join-work) to find records with the same ID and then compare the values.

```
select a.from from table1 a inner table1 b on a.id = b.id
where a.from = b.to
```

Comment: the 'where' could also be replace with 'and'

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you want?

```
select *
from table1 t
where exists (select 1 from table2 t2 where t2.`from` = t.id) and
      exists (select 1 from table2 t3 where t3.`to` = t.id);
```

Comment: They are two tables only,  one we get the main id from (that stands for FROM and TO in 2 different records) and the other table (x) contains FROM,TO,ID ... So, I want to get table  (x) ID

Comment: @Naughty.Coder . . . That really doesn't change the idea behind the query.  I made the changes.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure If understand it correctly.

If `User_ID` from `Table_1` should be present in `From` AND in `To` columns from Table_2 AND for those records also ID in `Table_2` must be same,

Then for those condition will be eligible not only `User_ID` 16 and 15 as you mentioned in your example but also for 0 and 2.

Assuming that is correct.

Then try this code (for mySQL you probably have to change some syntax):

```
SELECT A.*  
FROM Table_1 AS A
INNER JOIN Table_2 AS B ON (A.USER_ID=B.FROM)
INNER JOIN Table_2 AS C ON (A.USER_ID=C.TO AND C.ID = B.ID)
```