# Need to find duplicates with multiple criteria and then comparing dates between duplicates

Tags: mysql, duplicates

I am writing annual membership registrations to a single db table.  I need to keep track of when renewals have occurred in less than 11 months from their last renewal.

I look for the duplicate rows based on multiple criteria.  I currently have this working with out the 11 month criteria, although it's slow.  Here's what I currently use.

```
    SELECT y_reg.* FROM y_reg WHERE (((y_reg.season) In (SELECT season FROM y_reg As Tmp 
    GROUP BY season, Father_Last_Name, Father_First_Name 
    HAVING Count(*)>1  
    AND Father_Last_Name = y_reg.Father_Last_Name 
    AND Father_First_Name = y_reg.Father_First_Name))) 
    ORDER BY y_reg.season, y_reg.Father_Last_Name, y_reg.Father_First_Name
```

I have a field `Date` which is the date of the renewal that I need to evaluate. I'd like to add something like "AND `Date` - `Date` < 335"
335 is the number of days and is about 1 month short of a year.  But I just keep getting syntax error because I clearly don't know what I'm doing.

Comment: I need to show all duplicate row in the output.  It seems that adding any kind of 
    
    AND b.Date <  a.Date - 11 MONTH
    AND b.Date >= a.Date - 12 MONTH
    
causes the original row not to be returned.  Is there a way to use the date different criteria without filtering out the mating duplicates in the output?

Comment: I was not able to get a solution here in this post.  However I founf a solution here: [link]http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32414978/mysql-find-and-show-all-duplicates-within-date-difference-critria

Answer (score 0):

[Date arithmetic](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_last-day) works quite well in MySQL; you just need the knack.

You can say things like

```
    AND later.Date >= earlier.Date
    AND later.Date < earlier.Date + INTERVAL 11 MONTH
```

That particular pair of comparisons comes up true if the later date occurs in the time range between the earlier date and 11 months later.

In general you can say stuff like this to do date arithmetic.

```
   datestamp + INTERVAL 1 HOUR
   datestamp - INTERVAL 5 MINUTE
   datestamp + 1 MONTH - 3 WEEK
   datestamp - INTERVAL 3 QUARTER  (calendar quarters)
   LAST_DAY(datestamp) + INTERVAL 1 DAY - INTERVAL 1 MONTH
```

The last item is the first day of the month containing the datestamp. This whole date thing works quite well.

I think you should consider a so-called [self-join](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1284441/how-does-a-mysql-self-join-work) query to get your duplicate-except-for-date results.  Try something like this.

```
 SELECT a.* 
   FROM y_reg a
   JOIN y_reg b   ON a.Father_Last_Name = b.Father_Last_Name
                 AND a.Father_First_Name = b.Father_First_Name
                 AND b.Date <  a.Date - 11 MONTH
                 AND b.Date >= a.Date - 12 MONTH
```

Comment: Thanks. The new select is lightening fast compared to my original one.  It seems to return single records maybe because a & b have the same records.  I need to only display them when the match count is greater than one. then order by last, first.

        WHERE Count(*) >1
        GROUP BY Father_Last_Name, Father_First_Name

But am getting a syntax error for not using group and count properly.

Comment: I'm up to this point with no syntax errors

SELECT earlier.*
   FROM y_reg earlier
JOIN y_reg later   ON earlier.Father_Last_Name = later.Father_Last_Name
AND earlier.Father_First_Name = later.Father_First_Name
AND later.Date < earlier.Date - INTERVAL 11 MONTH
AND later.Date >= earlier.Date - INTERVAL 12 MONTH
GROUP BY Father_Last_Name, Father_First_Name
HAVING Count(*) >1
ORDER BY earlier.Year, earlier.Father_Last_Name, earlier.Father_First_Name

Still only returning single rows without it's dup returned at all rather than the two or more dups right next to each other as in the original.

Comment: I'm still stuck on this one.  I'm only returning a single row of the duplicates.  I need them to all show so that the user can decide which one to delete.