# MYSQL - find and show all duplicates within date difference critria

Tags: mysql, duplicates

This query below selects all rows that have a row with the same father registering 335 days or less since earlier registration. Is there a way to edit this query so that it does not eliminate the duplicate row in the output?  I need to see all instances of the registration for that father within 335 days of each other.

```
SELECT * FROM ymca_reg a later
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT 1 FROM ymca_reg a earlier 
    WHERE 
        earlier.Father_First_Name = later.Father_First_Name
        AND earlier.Father_Last_Name = later.Father_Last_Name
        AND (later.Date - earlier.Date < 335) AND (later.Date > earlier.Date)
```

My current query is:

```
SELECT ymca_reg.* FROM ymca_reg WHERE (((ymca_reg.Year) In (SELECT Year FROM ymca_reg As Tmp 
    GROUP BY Year, Father_Last_Name, Father_First_Name 
    HAVING Count(*)>1  
        And Father_Last_Name = ymca_reg.Father_Last_Name 
        And Father_First_Name = ymca_reg.Father_First_Name))) 
    ORDER BY ymca_reg.Year, ymca_reg.Father_Last_Name, ymca_reg.Father_First_Name
```

This query does return all the duplicates for review correctly, but it's terribly slow because it doesn't use a join and as soon as I add the date criteria it only returns the later row. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want something like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM ymca_reg later
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1
              FROM ymca_reg earlier 
              WHERE earlier.Father_First_Name = later.Father_First_Name AND
                    earlier.Father_Last_Name = later.Father_Last_Name AND
                    abs(later.Date - earlier.Date) < 335 and
                    later.Date <> earlier.Date
             );
```

This should return all records that have such duplicates.  Note that "later" and "earlier" are no longer really apt descriptions, but I left the names so you can see the similarity to your query.

Comment: Excellent.  That did the trick for the dups. All dups are returned and it's only evaluating dups within the date range. It does, however, return some single rows where there is no dup in the database.  Not sure why it would return only some unique's and not all unique's.

Comment: I spoke too soon.  I wasn't being very observant.  It is returning every row in the table, dupe or not.  I did add the 

`ORDER BY ymca_reg.Year, ymca_reg.Father_Last_Name, ymca_reg.Father_First_Name`

to bring the dupes next to each other. But that's not the cause.

Comment: That did it.  That's so much for your help Gordon.